# Blue sticker from Gemeente on my bike?

Tags: netherlands

I found a blue sticker from Gemeente on my bike this morning. As far as I know, this means I didn't move my bike for a long time and they will take it. But I used it two days ago.

I just removed this sticker. Is there something else I should do?

Comment: What was on the sticker (text)?

Comment: Which 'gemeente'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm right it doesn't mean that you didn't use it for a long time.

It is used as a marker. Next time they are here and they see it on the bike. It means no one used bike for that period otherwise the owner would take it from the bike. So it means they can collect and utilise it.

Comment: So, removing this sticker was the right thing to be done?

Comment: Correct, by this you're confirming that this bike is in active use

Comment: Note that [the site from the gemeente](https://www.amsterdam.nl/veelgevraagd/?caseid=%7B2F473143-FF3F-4B65-8199-51B96C8010B9%7D) mentions a **red** sticker ([example here](https://www.nrc.nl/nieuws/2015/12/11/fiets-wegboos-maar-te-lui-om-hem-op-te-halen-1565961-a70675), so I'm not sure this is the correct answer. [The Hague and Utrecht use several colors](https://www.rekenkamer.amsterdam.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/OZR-Verwijderen-van-fietsen_met-kaft_DEF.pdf), blue among them.

Comment: O sorry, I misread. Nowhere was Amsterdam specifically mentioned.

Comment: Your edit makes sense.  The sticker is more of a test to see whether the bike is in use than an assertion that it is not in use.

Answer (score 1):

You are right Ahmed, it means that your bike seems to have not been used for a long time. It warns you that if you do not use your bike it will be removed by city officials.
On the sticker it also says that if you ARE using the bike, you can remove the sticker. Most of the time these stickers are placed on bikes that are in spots where people in the neighbourhood feel they are out of place, like against their window or against the wall of a house.
Is your bike in a designated area, like in a bicycle rack?

Comment: Yes, it was on a bicycle rack and the sticker wasn't only on my bike but all the bicycles. I feel like they put it randomly, I don't know why !!

Comment: Because they don't know which of the bikes in the rack are in active use and which are junkers so they just sticker them all. Its quite common in Utrecht too.

Comment: @anomuse thanks for your reply, I did and till now no one take it from me :)